# ng-click does not work in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Below is the code. The click event does not work. in ng-click i have included  "insertTom()".

GOOGLE CDN : https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js

```
  var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

  var students = [{name:'Mary Contrary', id:'1'},

                  {name:'Jack Sprat', id:'2'},

                   {name:'Jill Hill', id:'3'}];

  function StudentListController($scope) {

      $scope.students = students;

      $scope.insertTom = function () {

      $scope.students.splice(1, 0, {name:'Tom Thumb', id:'4'});

  };
```

}

Comment: Did you define an ng-controller on the parent element that contains the ng-click.  Please post your template file

Comment: The code is incomplete. We can't see your ng-click, the hook of the controller to your module etc.

Comment: @OferZelig I tried to post the html template but I could not find a way to post in the description. The html tags disappear when I copy and paste it into the description area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-controller="StudentListController">
  <!-- content -->
  <button type="button" ng-click="insertTom()">Insert</button>
</div>
```

No problem, you will enjoy angular :)